# How to get logged in username in config file in RoundCube?

Tags: php, database, email, imap, roundcube

Here I want to get loggedin username from Roundcube.
The problem occurs to me is session starts after config so I am not able to get here I tried Using Environment Variable but then also I was unable to get it. i tried to store all this in cache as well the  fail. Can anyone advice or help to do this I want to make Roundcube db for every single user.

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'sqlite:////home/user/roundcube/username.db?mode=0660';
```

Comment: https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=28876.0

Comment: I am not using cPanel So that is not worth to me. And in that they want to login directly without using domain name.